# DeviceOrientationEvent's Alpha, Beta, Gamma values... can someone help explain on how to visualize?

Tags: javascript, mobile, dom-events

[According to this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation), `alpha` value represents the motion of the device around the z axis and goes from 0 to 360 degrees. The  `beta`  is the motion around the x-axis and goes from -180 to 180. Finally, `gamma` is the motion of the device around the y-axis and ranges from -90 to 90.

What I'm confused about is that, shouldn't all of them have a 360 degree sweep?  Also, where would the 0 degree be for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't researched this in depth, so take this answer with some salt.

0, 0, 0 is the natural position of the device.

You can resolve any orientation with those values.  If you think of gamma from -90 to 90, that would be like taking your phone from one edge to the other.

Now, what if you wanted to continue rolling left to right so that your phone is upside down?  Your beta value will be >90 degrees (or <-90 degrees).

Basically, you don't need 360 on each measurement to determine the gamut of orientations.